# HttpClient best practices in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, .net, azure, httpclient, azure-functions

I need to build an Azure Function that:

- Responds to a `HTTP POST` request
- Does 7x `HTTP HEAD` requests based on the data.

I've found some guidance [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1806) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Managing-Connections#httpclient)

But, it's not entirely clear what to do, and how it works?

As in the second link, i've currently just declared a `private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();` instance, and re-used that in my 7x HTTP HEAD calls.

My questions:

1. Is that the most efficient use of `HttpClient` in a stateless Azure function?
2. I'm currently just building up a `List<Task>()` for the http calls, then doing `Task.WhenAll(tasks)` on them to run them in parrallel. Would that be the quickest way to do these calls? Any other suggestions?

This Function endpoint will be called a lot (multiple times a second), so need to be as efficient as possible to keep costs down.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - this is still the current guidance for Azure Functions 1.x (and applies to 2.x as well) to best avoid socket exhaustion. The static variable will ensures that it will be shared against all instances of the class. Another good article that covers this topic is https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong

Comment: Thanks. That article is 2016 though? Is there nothing more recent showing it's still the best way? Not doubting you, just want to make sure :)

Comment: At least in regards to 1.x of Azure Functions and the .net framework 4.x not a lot has changed that would affect the guidance since 2016 :)   

Azure Functions 2.x though may bring in some new options\best practices since it sits on .net core 2.1 . I suspect the guidance will largely be the same (maximize reuse) but there is some new httpclient related constructs such as HttpClientFactory (https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore) that may introduce some new or additional options\guidance.

Comment: This solution really is NOT a correct usage of HttpClient in general. Holding one instance is also wrong als DNS changes don't get through. You will eventually lose all connectivity. That's why there is HttpClientFactory - but only in ASP .Net Core 2.1. My question now is: what should we do now?

Comment: @RPM1984 - Official documentation from Microsoft on this [can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections). However as Zordid mentions, if you can use the newer HttpClientFactory that's better.

Answer (score 27):

As of 2019, and v2/v3+ of the runtime, you also have the option to [use dependency injection in .NET Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection). Be aware that this only applies to .NET functions (C#), and AFAIK is not available for the other flavours, like Python, JavaScript/TypeScript etc.

Simple answer is that you can add a **Startup.cs** class to your Azure Function where your register the dependencies:

```cs
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyInjectedFunction.Startup))]

public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // Note: Only register dependencies, do not depend or request those in Configure().
        // Dependencies are only usable during function execution, not before (like here).
        
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
        // builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, MyLoggerProvider>();
    }
}
```

Pretty much the same as any other web/api project with dotnet core. Next, in your function itself, **add a constructor** and register the dependencies as parameters. You also want to remove the `static` modifier from your function. An example:
ref :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#register-services

```cs
public class MyInjectedFunction
{
    private readonly HttpClient _http;
    
    public MyInjectedFunction(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _http = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    }
    
    [FunctionName("my-injected-function")]
    public async Task RunAsync([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log)
    {
        var response = await _http.GetAsync("https://stackoverflow.com");
        
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            log.LogInformation("Okidoki");
        else
            log.LogError($"{response.StatusCode} {response.ReasonPhrase}: ");
    }
}
```

By using DI you can explicitly register it as singleton as well. Or created typed HttpClients. And personally, I think this is quite elegant.

Comment: I read this in the Azure docs but it's not clear about how it's creating the HttpClient in the function.  Apparently Azure functions have a host DI container that is "holding" every requested instance of the function and providing the HttpClient as a singleton to ALL function instances and therefore you cannot change the BaseUri after the first time it's been configured.  So, if it's in fact a singleton and can't be modified then where is the appropriate place to configure the HttpClient?

Comment: You can configure and add different HTTP clients in the startup with different names. And can use get clients by name when initiating IHttpClientFactory. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65095260/2775159

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that may be useful if Dependency Injection is unavailable, or if you have a dynamic list of HttpClients that will be knows at runtime. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/errors-diagnostics/sdk-rules/azf0002)

> - Move your HttpClient instantiation to a static instance defined outside of the function, such as in this example.
> - Supply an HttpClient to your functions using IHttpClientFactory through dependency injection. This is the recommended approach for fixing this violation.
>   )

This is the first option - using a static instance. It stores all HttpClients as a static list and accesses them by Uri. If already present in the list, the client will be reused, otherwise it will be created and added to the list.

```
        private static List<HttpClient> clients = new List<HttpClient>();

        private static HttpClient GetClient(Uri url)
        {
            var client = clients?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BaseAddress == url);
            if (client == null)
            {
                client = new HttpClient(new SocketsHttpHandler { PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), UseCookies = false, MaxConnectionsPerServer = 1000 })
                {
                    BaseAddress = url,
                    Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0)
                };
                clients.Add(client);
            }
            return client;
        }
```