# Get name HttpClient from IHttpClientFactory injected with DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor-webassembly, scrutor

In Blazor I have setup two HttpClients. One for my API and one for MS Graph API.
The Graph API is new, and have forced me to find a way to inject a named httpclient in to my services.

This is all the code in Main

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        b.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

        var samsonApiUrl = new Uri(b.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress + "api/");

        b.Services.AddHttpClient("SamsonApi",client => 
        {
           client.BaseAddress = samsonApiUrl;
           // add jwt token to header
           // add user agent to header
        }).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
        
        b.Services.AddTransient<GraphCustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
        b.Services.AddHttpClient<GraphHttpClientService>("GraphAPI",
                client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/"))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<GraphCustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
        
        b.Services.AddScoped(provider => provider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("SamsonApi"));
        b.Services.AddScoped(provider => provider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("GraphAPI"));
        
        b.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount>(options =>
        {
            b.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
            options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("1c8d4e31-97dd-4a54-8c2b-0d81e4356bf9/API.Access");
            options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role";
        }).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount, CustomUserFactory>();
        
        
        // add Radzen services 
        b.Services.AddScoped<DialogService>();
        b.Services.AddScoped<NotificationService>();
        b.Services.AddScoped<TooltipService>();
        // add samson component services
        b.Services.AddSingleton<FormTitleState>();
        // Add Http Services
        b.Services.Scan(scan =>
            {
                scan.FromAssemblyOf<ICustomerService>()
                    .AddClasses(classes => classes.Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Service")))
                    .AsMatchingInterface()
                    .WithScopedLifetime();
            });
        await b.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

This is the code that has to change.
It's scan all my service and get a HttpClient injected.
And since I now have two I get a random client injected.
How can I inject a named client into all of my services? I can handle the graph API service as a special case.

```
b.Services.Scan(scan =>
{
    scan.FromAssemblyOf<ICustomerService>()
        .AddClasses(classes => classes.Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Service")))
        .AsMatchingInterface()
        .WithScopedLifetime();
});
```

Example of a service calling my API

```
public class ActiveAgreementService : IActiveAgreementService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    
    public ActiveAgreementService(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<List<ActiveAgreementDto>> GetActiveAgreements()
    {
        var lst = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<ActiveAgreementDto[]>("ActiveAgreement");
        return lst.ToList();
    }
}
```

Okay ended up with replacing HttpClient with IHttpClientFactory in all my services

```
public UserService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{
   _client = clientFactory.CreateClient("SamsonApi");
}
```

Comment: why inject an http client?  You could always inject the factory and create a client via name in your service constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're using ASP.NET Core, although it's not clear which dependency injection framework you're using.

In that case, you could have your classes depend on `IHttpClientFactory` and then setup the configuration with [named clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#named-clients):

```
// Named client like you're currently doing
b.Services.AddHttpClient("SamsonApi", client => 
{
    client.BaseAddress = samsonApiUrl;
    // add jwt token to header
    // add user agent to header
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

//...

b.Services.AddHttpClient("GraphAPI", client =>
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<GraphCustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

// And in your dependent class
public class ActiveAgreementService : IActiveAgreementService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    
    public ActiveAgreementService(IHttpClientFactory clientFac)
    {
        // Whichever one you need:
        _client = clientFac.CreateClient("SamsonApi");
        _client = clientFac.CreateClient("GraphAPI");
    }

    public async Task<List<ActiveAgreementDto>> GetActiveAgreements()
    {
        var lst = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<ActiveAgreementDto[]>("ActiveAgreement");
        return lst.ToList();
    }
}
```

... or with [typed clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#typed-clients) you specify the instance for each class that depends on it:

```
// This HttpClient is only injected into ActiveAgreementService
b.Services.AddHttpClient<ActiveAgreementService>(client => 
{
    client.BaseAddress = samsonApiUrl;
    // add jwt token to header
    // add user agent to header
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

//...

// This HttpClient is only injected into GraphHttpClientService
b.Services.AddHttpClient<GraphHttpClientService>(client =>
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<GraphCustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

// And in your dependent class
public class ActiveAgreementService : IActiveAgreementService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    
    public ActiveAgreementService(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<List<ActiveAgreementDto>> GetActiveAgreements()
    {
        var lst = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<ActiveAgreementDto[]>("ActiveAgreement");
        return lst.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using the build in serviceprovider. I was also thinking of injecting the IHttpClientFactory  but the I have to change 25 classes (: I like that I just can ccreate a new service class and have it injected without remembering to register it

Comment: Not sure I follow. If you need a differently configured client to be injected, you'll always have to register it. But of course if you have multiple service classes using the same configuration of an `HttpClient` then a named client is probably what you want. Changing from `HttpClient` to `IHttpClientFactory` should not take many minutes