# RestSharp.RestClient 107 in Azure Function throws "The type initializer for NAME threw an exception". No issue in RestSharp 106.10

Tags: azure-functions, restsharp

In an Azure Function a static helper class uses RestSharp 106 like this:

```
public static class InsightlyHelper
{
   private static readonly RestClient RestClient = new RestClient { 
      BaseUrl = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("InsightlyApiBaseUrl") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()) 
   };
```

I switched to RestSharp 107 which uses the HttpClient and changed the code to this:

```
public static class InsightlyHelper
{
   private static readonly RestClient RestClient = new RestClient(new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("InsightlyApiBaseUrl")));
```

But this error gets thrown: [Error] Failed to create new SUDB project for insightly project. Error was The type initializer for 'SU_API.Infrastructure.InsightlyHelper' threw an exception.

I have seen the [Migration guide](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107)

I am thinking of trying to dependency inject RestClient to this helper class and another similar class, anyone tried that?  Or other suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- Try adding the below code in csproj file:

```
<Target Name="PostPublish" BeforeTargets="Publish">
  <Exec Command="move $(PublishDir)\runtimes $(PublishDir)\bin" />
</Target>
```

- The exception may occur due to external dependencies "RestSharp.dll" is not added. Try by adding one.

Answer (score 0):

Using the dependency injection code pattern worked.  I based this off [HttpClient best practice in Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276617/httpclient-best-practices-in-azure-functions) This set of functions contains helper classes (one per external API) instantiated as singletons, injected into functions.  Now each of these helper classes gets IHttpClientFactory injected, and passes a HttpClient to an instance of a RestSharp RestClient.

The StartUp.cs looks like

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(SU_API.Startup))]
namespace SU_API
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IInsightlyHelper, InsightlyHelper>();
        }
    }
}
```

An example API helper looks like

```
public class InsightlyHelper : IInsightlyHelper
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly RestClient RestClient;
    private static readonly RestClientOptions RestClientOptions = new() {BaseUrl = new Uri("https//someuri")};
    public InsightlyHelper(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        RestClient = new RestClient(_httpClient, RestClientOptions);
    }
}
```

And an API helper gets injected like this

```
public class InsightlyUpdateMmwLink
{
    private readonly IInsightlyHelper _insightlyHelper;
    public InsightlyUpdateMmwLink(IInsightlyHelper insightlyHelper)
        {
            _insightlyHelper = insightlyHelper;
        }
}
```