# Azure function: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=7.0.0.0'

Tags: c#, azure-functions, httpclient

i have an azure function and i wanto to do a post with HttpClient to an endpoint of a certain API.
I run the project without error but when the function start it throw this error. What i have to do to solve it? I searched and found a lot but nothing usefull or cleary explained.

[image]

Function :

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using Tesi.Worker;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace Tesi.Worker
{
    public class StandingsFunctions
    {
        private static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

        public StandingsFunctions()
        {
        }

        [FunctionName("WeeklyUpdateStandings")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            HttpContent content = null; 
            var response =  _client.PostAsync("https://sportdataapi.azurewebsites.net/api/WebHook/UpdateStandings",content);

            if (response.IsCompletedSuccessfully) { log.LogInformation("Post andata a buon fine " + response.Status.ToString()); }
            else { log.LogInformation("Errore!"); }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

framework contains System.http.net, where it's located in directory? How can i try to decrease the version to test if that is the problem?Can i delete the full framework and install all package by my self? (have sense?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276617/httpclient-best-practices-in-azure-functions. Hope this helps

Comment: Sounds like you're using an inprocess function app. It tries to remove redundant dll's, but does so a bit over aggressively causing these kinds of errors. In your `.csproj` try adding `<_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>` in the `<PropertyGroup>` and see if it works then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used below version of packages and its working fine for me:

[image]

`.csproj` file:

```xml
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
          <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

> How can i try to decrease the version to test if that is the problem?

You can find manage nuget packages as below:

Firstly right click on Your Function App name :

[image]

Then right click and click on `Manage Nuget Packages`:

[image]

Type in Search Box, name of the package and then click on the Package name and select the version you want and then Update.

If this doesn't work then start a new Function App and install my Packages and it will work fine as i got Output too.

```
Output:
```

[image]

Comment: Example [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74470489/system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-exte/74473381#74473381)

Comment: Thanks, was the correct idea. Probably in one of my try to solve the problem i updated .Net 6 to 7. For that, some new features cause conflict or are changed from the version that i know. So, i downgrade to version 6 and downgrade the SDK as you said and it works.

Comment: Glad it solved the problem.